# How to extract values of maximum displacement in abaqus?

Tags: python, session

```
square_odb_Path='squaremodalanalysis.odb'
squareodb=session.openodb(name=square_odb_Path)
max_displacement=0
for x in range(len(squareodb.steps['Loading Step'].frames[-1]\.fieldoutputs['U'].values[0].instance.nodes)):
```

Getting error in line 4!

Comment: i think your getting an error because there is nothing in the for loop

Comment: How to solve it as i am new to python. I need a code for to get nodes with maximum displacements values in abaqus.

Comment: square_odb_Path='squaremodalanalysis.odb'
squareodb=session.openodb(name=square_odb_Path)

Comment: max_displacement=0
for x in range(len(squareodb.steps['Loading Step'].frames[-1]\.fieldoutputs['U'].values[0].instance.nodes)):
node_y_displacement = abs(squareodb.steps['Loading Step'].frames[-1]\.fieldoutputs['U'].values[x].data[1]):
if node_y_displacement > max_displacement:
max_disp_node_label = squareodb.steps['Loading Step'].frames[-1]\.fieldoutputs['U'].values[x].nodeLabel
field_output_dip_object_index = x
max_displacement = node_y_displacement

Comment: print'\n\n'
print 'The node with the maximum Y displacement is %d' %max_disp_node_label
print 'The Y component of the displacement is %f' %max_displacement
print 'The magnitude of the displacement (length of disp vector) is %.5f' \ %squareodb.steps['Loading Step'].frames[-1].fieldoutputs['U'] \ .values[field_output_disp_object_index].magnitude
print '\n\n'
print '======================================='

Comment: This one is complete code

Comment: Then please edit your question an put your whole code there

Comment: Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50730622/edit) if you don't know how to edit a question